# Cluster spatial - cannot allocate vector

Tags: vector, file-size

I'm trying use this code for create cluster spatial in R, I get from @ssanch:

```
# example data from the thread

x <- c(-22.83982, -23.49961, -27.08745, -22.98890, -19.92278)
y <- c(-47.20671, -46.85583, -52.62162, -43.22838, -43.95431)

# convert data to a SpatialPointsDataFrame object
xy <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(
  matrix(c(x,y), ncol=2), data.frame(ID=seq(1:length(x))),
  proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"))

# use the distm function to generate a geodesic distance matrix in meters
mdist <- distm(xy)

# cluster all points using a hierarchical clustering approach
hc <- hclust(as.dist(mdist), method="complete")

# define the distance threshold, in this case 40 m
d=275000

# define clusters based on a tree "height" cutoff "d" and add them to the SpDataFrame
xy$clust <- cutree(hc, h=d)
```

But I change the latitude and longitude for my data with 600k registers and the R can't processing with this errors:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 8.0 Gb

Is there any solution?

Comment: Which line gives that error? Are you trying to do this with 600,000 points ("registers")? That is a matrix that is 600,000 x 600,000 - a matrix with 3x10^11 elements. Your machine doesn't have enough RAM for that. You may need to rethink why you are doing this clustering.

Comment: Eu preciso criar clusters a partir da distancia entre clientes, se a distancia entre os pontos for menor que determinado valor e agrupa-los. Conhece outra maneira de fazer?

Comment: @rodolforogerdossantos Please note that this is an English language site. Could you translate your comment to English please?

Comment: @Aaron sorry!!!! I need to create clusters from the distance between clients if the distance between the points is less than certain value and groups them together. Do you know another way to do it?

Comment: Does anyone have any solutions to my problem?